# How to address/reuse ReferencePoints in Abaqus-Python like other Abaqus-Python-Objects?

Tags: python, abaqus

While scripting Abaqus-Python, i frequently store objects in variables like `myAssembly` in order to shorten the code and to reliably address these objects later on. For example:

```
myAssembly = mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly
```

However, the return value of `myAssembly.ReferencePoint(point=(0.5, 0.5, 0.0))` is a FeatureObject and no "ReferencePoint" (see Abaqus 2016 Scripting Manual 20.1.58).

Therefore the code:

```
myReferencePoint = myAssembly.ReferencePoint(point=(0.5, 0.5, 0.0))
mySetMaster = myAssembly.Set(
    name='m_Set-1',
    referencePoints=(myReferencePoint, ))
```

results in "TypeError: referencePoints[0]; found Feature, expecting tuple".

The recorded journal uses (shortend by usage of `myAssembly`)

```
myAssembly.ReferencePoint(point=(0.5, 0.5, 0.0))
myAssembly.Set(name='m_Set-1', referencePoints=(
    myAssembly.referencePoints[4], ))
```

The question is: How can one address a ReferencePoint through usage of variables (e.g. `myReferencePoint`) instead of possibly changing numbers (e.g. `4`)?

Answer (score 1):

Its similar to the previous answer by @JulianBauer. Since Reference Points are assembly features, one can access it by

```
myReferencePoint = myAssembly.features[rpName]
mySetMaster = myAssembly.Set(
    name='m_Set-1',
    referencePoints=(myAssembly.referencePoints[myReferencePoint.id], ))
```

But, this does require one to know the reference point name before hand.

Comment: I extended my previous answer using your hint to `myReferencePoint.id`.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the method
`myAssembly.referencePoints.findAt(myRefPointCoord)`
to do the following workaround:

```
myRefPointCoord = (0.5, 0.5, 0.0)

myAssembly.ReferencePoint(point=myRefPointCoord)
mySetMaster = myAssembly.Set(
    name='m_Set-1',
    referencePoints=(myAssembly.referencePoints.findAt(myRefPointCoord), ))
```

Drawback: What if there are multiple reference points at the same location? This case is quite common.

## # # # # # #  # # # # # # # # # # #

If there are **multiple reference points** at the **same location:**

Inspired by [Subramani Anbazhagan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550769/8935243) 
I suggest to get the feature object of the reference point returned by the constructor and use this feature object's `id`:

```
myRPFeat = myAssembly.ReferencePoint(point=(0.5, 0.5, 0.0))
mySetMaster = myAssembly.Set(
    name='m_Set-1',
    referencePoints=(myAssembly.referencePoints[myRPFeat.id], ))
```

## # # # # # #  # # # # # # # # # #

Is there still a better way?